# When I use FSCalendar's API :selectDate appear 1970

Tags: ios, fscalendar

As my title, When I use FSCalendar's API **selectDate**. The headerDate According to 1970. That's my code.

```
 NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
 [_calendar selectDate: startDate];
```

Comment: This question only appear in ios 8

Comment: I suggest you post an issue on GitHub.